# How do I remove the search bar in ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, search

Is there a way to remove the search bar from all of the home screens in Ice Cream Sandwich?   I have a Nexus S, which already has a hard-button for search, so the search bar is redundant.  Long pressing on it doesn't seem to do anything useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't remove it from the stock launcher, it's a permanent fixture. You can, however, install a custom launcher which is based on the stock one like [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher&hl=en) or [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher).

You can also disable the [Google Search app completely](http://androidcommunity.com/ice-cream-sandwich-tweak-disable-the-home-screen-search-bar-20111201/) if you want to, but then you won't be able to use it at all ([also discussed on Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/mobile/p6gBLy3oQek)).

Comment: Disabling the Google Search app completely doesn't require root; I just did it.  But as far as I can tell, the only way I can search now is to either open the browser and type my search into its bar; or else long-press the search button and speak my search terms.

Comment: @offby1: Thanks, I'll update the part about needing root.